# Redis server behind traefik V2 in Docker swarm

Tags: docker, redis, docker-swarm, traefik

I have a running master/slaves redis servers, If I expose the port directly from the container it works and I can connect to the Redis instance; but if I try to connect via Traefik I get an error.

All containers are correctly registered in Traefik.

Here is my traefik config

```
    - "traefik.enable=true"
    - "traefik.docker.network=traefik-public"
    - "traefik.constraint-label=traefik-public"
    - "traefik.tcp.routers.redis-dev-connect.rule=HostSNI(`*`)"
    - "traefik.tcp.services.redis-dev-connect.loadbalancer.server.port=6379"
    - "traefik.tcp.routers.redis-dev-connect.entrypoints=caching"
    - "traefik.tcp.routers.redis-dev-connect.service=redis-dev-connect"
```

Do I need to add another option in Traefik or in the labels definition ?

Thanks,